# Big Query data pulled very slow on Looker Studio

Tags: google-bigquery

Im trying to load a specific table from Google Big Query to Looker Studio and most of the time it might take up to 5 minutes to load the data.
The BQ table is a view table that built from 4 different tables, I have aggregated the data so it will have less rows.
A simple query on the BQ console on that table takes few seconds but once Im trying to pull the data on Looker studio it takes up to 5 minutes. The total amount of data is 7 GB.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't generally happen, especially with data of that size. It's possible that job on BigQuery side was taking longer because of query queue (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-queues), or there may be fewer slots for on-demand queries at particular location, or slots available to current project. But both rarely lead to such a long runtime for such a small dataset.

Another thing to check: what is the output size? If dashboard needs to fetch all 7Gb, it may be very slow depending on connection.

One way to diagnose would be to enable Native Integration with LookerStudio that is currently in preview:[link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-looker-studio#looker-studio-integration)

It allows to have requests for each Datasource/Report logged in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS view, and any performance issues can be investigated based on BigQuery logs. See an example of query here in [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-looker-studio#view_jobs_produced_by_using_a_report_and_data_source)